# iTunes Connect, iOS build duplicated

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I just tried to upload a new build to iTunes Connect and make it available for internal/external testers. After I upload new build, I receive the "Processing completed" email for my build, but in the iOS Builds list I found a duplicated (in gray without logo) copy of my build with same build number and difference in upload time (couple of minutes)! I repeated the procedure and it's for every build I uploaded it's a copy of that is there. Here is screen shot:

[image]

The main problem is that when I try to add this build (9) to testFlight internal/external test, there is small blue circle with "!" says "Latest build is still in process" and I think it pointing the gray duplicate copy of my Build (number 9). 
Here is the screen shot of build to add for test (testFlight):

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is not an answer but I want to suggest to use third party test API. I prefer Fabric.io or HockeyApp..

Comment: @emresancaktar , will give them a try. thx

Answer (score 0):

I would probably make a new build and resubmit. Sometimes iTunes Connect can get confused. They had an outage yesterday as well that could have caused issues.

Adding a new build should fix things.

Comment: Thanks, I tried couple of times with different build number end even version number but nothing changed. P.S, I'm working on 2 apps in same time to publish. A client version and Administrator version. They have their own App ID but in "Certificates, Identifiers and Profiles", in "Identifiers" tab I just have information regarding one of my apps (Client version). Could it be the reason why iTunes Connect confused?!

Comment: UPDATE: I fixed above issue and again nothing changed!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I receive an email from apple engineers indicates they solve my problem, so maybe the answer is to contact apple and FOLLOW UP with your problem!